# Odd behavior with large double in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database storing VIN numbers (stored as VID) for vehicles which are 17 characters in length.  I am trying to increment to the next VID to display it on the page where a new vehicle can be added in the database.  The VID field in the database is type bigint(17) and has auto_increment set.

```
$incr_query = "SELECT MAX(VID) FROM Vehicle";
$incr_result = mysql_query($incr_query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($incr_result);
$vid = $row["MAX(VID)"] + 1;
```

Output:

```
print var_dump{$row);//array(1) { ["MAX(VID)"]=> string(17) "12345678123456788" }
print gettype($vid);    //double
print $vid;             //1.2345678123457E+16
print number_format(++$vid, 0, '.', '');       //12345678123456788
print number_format(--$vid, 0, '.', '');       //12345678123456788
print number_format($vid - 5, 0, '.', '');     //12345678123456784
```

I'm not sure what's going on here.  According to the [PHP float manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

```
"The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of ~1.8e308 with 
a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value"
```

**EDIT:**

So using bcadd, these are the outputs:

```
$vid = bcadd($vid, '1', 0); 
print "\n".$vid;                              //12345678123456789
print "\n".number_format($vid, 0, '.', '');   //12345678123456788
```

Comment: Well, it's not accurate enough, it seems? The number is more than 14 digits, so the estimation seems to hold for your architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VID number might **look** like a "double" or "integer" or whatever but it **isn't**. Store it as string. Check out [Skeet on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/7403673) for an explanation. It starts around 6:10 and ends at, around, 10:00.

A bigint in the DB might do, but a double is a [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) and floating points are [not intended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) to be used as discrete numbers; that's why they're floating points. I would go with string (varchar) all the way, up to the database. Using a bigint would encourage you/other developers to keep treating it as a "number" wich, in fact, it isn't (exactly).

Comment: I see what you mean about discrete vs continuous.  If I change it to a string in the database and in the script, how am I to increment it?

Comment: You could opt to keep the bigint in the DB for letting the DB handle the (auto)increment(ing). If you do, make sure you use use a `string` in your application. If you're going for `string`/`varchar` all-the-way as [per my earlier suggestion](http://riii.nl/ftew5) you'll need a bit more (application)logic to increment the number with help from, for example, [bcadd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php) from [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [gmp_add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-add.php) from [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).

Comment: I updated my question.  The number_format still outputs the same value for some reason.

Comment: Because number_format tries to cast the value you're passing into it into some form of number (double probably) and then tries to format it. **number**_format is not for formatting **strings** (of "bc_bignumbers" ;)

Comment: @theyshookhands I actually don't see why you are using number_format at all; you are passing the following arguments: the (string) $vid, then 0 for 0 decimal places, '.' for decimals separator (wich is of no use because you don't want decimal places, see previous argument passed in), and an empty thousands separator which would result in no thousands separator being used. So why bother using the number_format at all? And, I checked, [number_format](http://php.net/number_format) tries to cast the first argument to float indeed.

Comment: Well I was initially using it because it took the double out of scientific notation.  But, yes, I have no use for it anymore I was just curious why it still displayed the initial value (after it has been incremented).